# How can I overlay a topojson file on google maps?

Tags: google-maps, d3.js, overlay, topojson

Hi so I have a file called a topojson file that draws nyc school districts using the following code. But say I want to take this drawing and put it on top of a Google Map. How can I do this? How can I overlay this on a google map...I've tried a few methods but they didn't work and now I'm confused.

```
var sdData = {};

d3.json('nyc_school_districts.topojson', function(data){

var h = 500,
    w = 500,
    id = '',
    g;

var svg = d3.select('#map')
            .append('svg')
            .attr('height', h)
            .attr('width', w);

var proj = d3.geo.mercator()
                .center([-73.95,40.69])
                .scale(45000)
                .translate([w/2, h/2]);
var path = d3.geo.path().projection(proj);


// tip for map
var tip = d3.tip()
    .html(function(d){return '<b>' + d.id + '</b>'})

// mouseover for map
function mapMove() {

    return svg.call(tip);
};

var nyc = svg.selectAll("path")
            .data(topojson.feature(data,data.objects.nyc_school_districts).features)
            .enter()
            .append('path')
            .attr('class', function(d){return "sd "+ d.id})
            .attr('d', path)
            .on('mousemove', tip.show)
            .on('mouseout', tip.hide)
            .on('mouseover', function(d){id=d.id;mapMove()});
```

});

Comment: Yes it is possible.  It would really help if you could post an example of the data or even better post your code and data on something like [bl.ocks](http://bl.ocks.org/) or a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: See: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/899711